# MySQL clear the query cache for a specific database or query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running a database on a MySQL server that has dozens of databases, so

`RESET QUERY CACHE`

is not possible because I would be resetting it for all other databases.

I was curious whether it's possible to reset the query cache for just one database, or one query? Or is it possible to write a `SELECT` statement that doesn't use the query cache?

---

**Update**: I tried `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE` and `set session query_cache_type=0` but these didn't make any difference... which makes me think I'm running into disk or OS caches.

All I really want to do is benchmark... you'd think that MySQL would provide a way...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for a single socket all databases will share same my.cnf parameters. You can bind MYSQL on a different socket and have different instances of mysql running, then you can have query cache enabled or disabled.

But there is another solution, you can use memcached and store queries there so you can access from there if the need be, so that you can disable query cache. I understand query cache can cause contention.

Answer (score 0):

Can't we use SQL_NO_CACHE

Example: SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id, name FROM customer;

Comment: See my update. I tried that but it's not making a difference... perhaps b/c of disk or OS caching. Hard to benchmark!